# Rxjava `2.x` Crash when an exception is thrown

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

**RxJava version**

2.2.19

**Operating platform**

Android 8~11

**Question**

Firebase reported that `Flowable.error(new IllegalStateException("Illegal status"))` crashed.

It seems that what is thrown by the `error` operator does not enter the RxJava event stream correctly. How can I avoid this problem?

**Complete process (not actual business code)**

```java
Flowable.create(
                new FlowableOnSubscribe<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                        while (!emitter.isCancelled()){
                            // do something
                            String result = requestInfo();
                            if (result != null) {
                                emitter.onNext(result);
                            }
                        }
                        emitter.onComplete();
                    }
                }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .concatMap(new Function<String, Publisher<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Publisher<String> apply(String s) throws Exception {
                        if (s.isEmpty()) {
                            // A serious error occurred, stop it
                            // Note: Firebase reported here that it crashed
                            return Flowable.error(new IllegalStateException("Invalid data"));
                        } else {
                            return Flowable.just(s);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<String>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onStart() {
                        request(1);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                      // error handle
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid data.
```

Comment: Most likely your `DisposableSubscriber` was disposed and thus the error could not be delivered. Recommended reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling